# How to draw a circle on an image in android

Tags: java, android, image, screen, geometry

I loaded an image from drawable resources and I show it on android device's screen. I need to draw a circle on the image and update the place of the circle during times. Can anyone help me to figure the process out. 
This is my code for loading image which works perfectly:

```
    private void createBitMap() {

    Bitmap bitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);  //creates bmp
    bitMap = bitMap.copy(bitMap.getConfig(), true);     //lets bmp to be mutable
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitMap);                 //draw a canvas in defined bmp

    Paint paint = new Paint();                          //define paint and paint color
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    //paint.setStrokeWidth(0.5f);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);                           //smooth edges


    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.map);
    //canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 3, paint);
}
```

Comment: what is the problem you're having with that code if you uncomment the drawCircle line?

Comment: Thanks kelmer for your comment. If I do so, Nothing will happened more than the map loaded. actually commenting or uncommenting result the same.

Comment: Try calling drawCircle *before* setting the image resource to your view

Comment: I tried! nothing happened. If I skip  the two last lines and uncomment the convas.draw ... it will draw the circle as expected but I need the circle to be on the image.

Comment: You are setting the bitmap you use for drawing the circle, then setting anopther image from resources... which is replacing the bitmap. You can't call `setImageResource` if you want the bitmap to be displayed.

Comment: oh ok. So how to do that?

Comment: Use `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(null, R.drawable.map);` to create your bitmap.

Comment: I posted an answer with the code you should use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you set image resource after `setImageBitmap()` the bitmap will never be drawn in this case, if you want to load both map and circle in imageview than alter your code to full fill your requirements:

```
  private void createBitMap() {

    Bitmap bitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);  //creates bmp
    bitMap = bitMap.copy(bitMap.getConfig(), true);     //lets bmp to be mutable
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitMap);                 //draw a canvas in defined bmp

    Paint paint = new Paint();                          //define paint and paint color
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    //paint.setStrokeWidth(0.5f);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);                           //smooth edges


    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
    //changed set image resource to set image background resource
    imViewAndroid.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.map);
    canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 3, paint);
    //invalidate to update bitmap in imageview
    imageView.invalidate();

}
```

now the circle will be drawn.
cheers,
Hamad

Comment: if it works then,i think my answer is also eligible for upvote, so do upvote it. :) @HosseinDolatabadi

Comment: don't know how to! :) teach me

Comment: two arrows from the left of every question and answer,denotes that,on clicking on up arrow,the question will be upvoted and on clicking on down arrow,the question will be downvoted @HosseinDolatabadi

Comment: Good one, also help me

Comment: what is "imViewAndroid" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void createBitMap() {

    Bitmap bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(null, R.drawable.map);  //creates bmp
    bitMap = bitMap.copy(bitMap.getConfig(), true);     //lets bmp to be mutable
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitMap);                 //draw a canvas in defined bmp

    Paint paint = new Paint();                          //define paint and paint color
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    //paint.setStrokeWidth(0.5f);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);                           //smooth edges

    canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 3, paint);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
}
```

Comment: I get an error. The "decodeResource" is not recognized

Comment: sorry, my mistake. It's `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()`

Comment: No more error for the "decodeResource" but the app is getting closed unsuccessfully. What is the problem?!

Comment: I wouldn't know, what does your LogCat say?

Comment: I tried with my android device and the emulator but it wont start in none of them. nothing useful in the LogCast. only pointing error in java file.

Comment: What do you mean "pointing error in java file"? An error in compile-time? Does Eclipse underline any of your code?

Comment: No the error is in runtime. None of the java code's lines is picked as an error.

Comment: by the way do you know any link that can teach me what is the bitmap, canvas and paint for in details. It is hard (as a nightmare!) to shift from visual studio to some thing like eclipse and android :)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/ is your friend. Please give more details if you want us to be able to help you solving your error.